# Special case of Grothedieck's Freeness Lemma (Vakil 7.4. F)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

I've been doing section 7.4 of Vakil's notes on Algebraic Geometry and there is a series of exercises to prove **Grothendieck's Generic Freeness Lemma**. The first exercise, special case of the lemma, is to prove the following:

> Let $B$ be a Noetherian integral domain and $M$ a finitely generated $B$ module. Then there exist a nonzero $f\in B$ such that $M_f$ is a free $B_f$-module.

Proofs of the above that I've seen (e.g in Matsumura, I think) make use of existence of a filtration

$0=M_0\subset M_1\subset \ldots \subset M_n=M$ with $M_{i+1}/M_i\cong B/\mathfrak{p_i}$,

with $\mathfrak{p}\subset B$ a prime ideal. I think there is an easier approach (i.e. not requiring above statement) to prove this particular case:

---

Take $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n$ to be generators of $M$ as a $B$-module. Let $\mathfrak{a}_i=\text{Ann}(x_i)$. Then $\mathfrak{a}_i\subset B$ is an ideal of Noetherian ring $B$, thus is finitely generated. We reorder $i$'s so that $\mathfrak{a}_i\neq (0)$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$ and $\mathfrak{a}_i=(0)$ for all $i>r$ (with $0\leq r \leq n$). If $r=0$, then $M\cong B^n$ and is free. Otherwise, we have $\mathfrak{a}_i=(f_{i1},\ldots , f_{in_i})$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$. Take $f=\prod f_{ij}$ of all generators for all nontrivial $\mathfrak{a_i}$'s. Then $f\neq 0$ and $M_f\cong B_f^{n-r}$ via homomorphism

$\phi: a_1x_1+\ldots + a_nx_n\mapsto (a_{r+1},a_{r+2},\ldots , a_{n})$

which obviously is onto. For all $1\leq i\leq r$ we have $x_i\sim 0$ in $M_f$, since $fx_i=0$ in $M$. Therefore $\phi$ is injective as well, so it is an isomorphism.

---

Is this proof correct or is there a mistake in it, which gives the reason for thinking about that special case necessarily in terms of the Matsumura's approach?

Comment: Start with the fact that $S^{-1}M$ is a finitely generated module over $S^{-1}B$ for any multiplicatively closed subset and in particular for $S=B-\{0\}$, making $S^{-1}B$ to be a field and thus $S^{-1}M$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: But $S$ must be generated by a single nonzero element (and $S=B-\{0\}$ does not have to be generated by single element). Did you take it into account?

Comment: @aleph_zero Why $\mathfrak a_i=(0)$ for all $i$ makes $(x_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ a basis (as I suppose you thought)?

Comment: @aleph_zero It was a suggestion. Using finite generated property, you can find a single element to do what you want from there-just take the product of all the denominators appearing in a basis.

Comment: @user26857 I see, it doesn't mean that then $\sum a_ix_i=0$ imply $a_i=0$. But if this is not the case, then we can take the largest set of generators to be linearly independent as above, say $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_s$. Then for all $i<s$ there is $a_i\neq 0$ such that $a_i$ is a linear combination of $x_1,x_2,\ldots , x_s$. Then we take $a=(b,f^l)$ to be the product of those and localise to get $(M_{bf})$. Then it is generated as $B_{bf}$-module and we have a "linear independence" of $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_s$, and then we can construct an isomorphism with $B_{bf}^s$.

Comment: @Mohan This seems at least a bit suspicious: one can always multiply the basis elements by suitable units (in the fraction field) to obtain a basis with all the denominators being $1$. For this basis, one would then get $f=1$, so if your argument works (and I understand it correctly), this would lead to $M \simeq M_1$ being free $B$-module.

Comment: @PavelČoupek I do not understand what you mean. What I said was completely standard.

Comment: @Mohan Maybe I misunderstood what you mean by "denominators appearing in the basis". That sounds like taking $f_1, \dots, f_n$ when your basis is $x_1/f_1, \dots x_n/f_n\; (x_i \in M, f_i \in B \setminus \{0\})$. But these denominators can be always taken trivial, since if the above $n$ elements form a basis, then so do $x_1=f_1\cdot (x_1/f_1), \dots x_n=f_n\cdot (x_n/f_n)$. Then the product of the denominators would simply be $1$.

Comment: @Mohan It seems to me that one should instead observe that this basis can be taken as elements $x_1,  \dots, x_n \in M$. Then the submodule $N=\sum_i Bx_i$ is free, and the correct choice of $f$ would be some nonzero $f$ inside the annihilator of $M/N$. If you meant something like this, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I suppose @Mohan wants to say the following: take a system of generators $(z_i)$ in $M$ and a basis $(x_j/1)$ in $S^{-1}M$, write $z_i/1\in S^{-1}M$ in this basis and consider $f$ the product of all the denominators of all coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, your prove becomes false at the point, where you claim that the $x_i$ form a basis, if all of them are torsion free. Just take a non-principal ideal in a Dedekind domain. The two generators are both torsion-free, but they dont form a basis.

Actually the prove in this special case is much easier, you just do the natural thing. Get a basis over the fraction field and add the denominators needed. Concretely, you do the following:

Let $S = B - \{0\}$ and $K = S^{-1}B$ the fraction field of $B$. The $x_1, \dotsc, x_n$ generate $S^{-1}M$ as a $K$-vector space, i.e. we can extract a basis, say $x_1, \dotsc, x_m$ with $m \leq n$.

Now write each of $x_{m+1}, \dotsc, x_n$ as $K$-linear combinations of this basis. Let $f$ be the product of all denominators occuring. Then these are actually $B_f$-linear combinations, i.e. $x_1, \dotsc, x_m$ generate $M_f$ as a $B_f$-module.

$x_1, \dotsc, x_m$ are clearly $B_f$-linear independent, since they are $K$-linear independent. Thus $M_f$ is $B_f$-free.